# Unable to reach Github

Tags: github

i am unable to reach github without using vpn from last few days

[image]

Can anyone tell me the reason and solution of this problem?

Comment: Tried flushing your DNS (ipconfig /flushdns)? This isn't quite a programming question.

Comment: I have tried flushing DNS but it did not work for me. I know it's not a programming question but i asked if someone could help

Comment: Are you using a proxy?